# Pandas split column by combined delimiters

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where the delimiter is set to be in this format "|"

Previously I tried this but it didnt work out.

```
df.str.split('"|"', expand = True)
```

Below is an example of my dataset. both strings are captured in a single column in csv format.

```
"COLUMN_A"|"COLUMN_B"
"MARY"|"HADALITTLELAMB"
```

Ideally I should see this

| COLUMN_A | COLUMN_B |
| --- | --- |
| MARY | HAD A LITTLE LAMB |

Comment: How did you read the data? if from a text file, maybe `pd.read_csv(file.txt, sep='\|')` helps.

Comment: ```str.split``` needs to be applied to a series, do you mean ```df['column_name'].str.split('|', expand=True)```?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply I actually found an answer to this already. Will be posting it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I manage to find an answer. Basically to treat this whole string of delimiter "|" as a single delimiter, we have to implement it this way.

```
df.str.split('\"\|\"', expand = True)
```